# How to populate a select box with the selected values of another select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a multiselect `select` box whose values are something like Object_1, Object_2... Object_10.
When I click a button after selecting values, I can write selected values below, but I want to populate another select box with those selected values.

Here is my code for the select box:

```
  <body style="background-color: azure;" ng-app="app">
    <div id="container" style="padding: 50px 100px 50px 200px; width: 80%" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <div class="block" style="padding: 15px;">
            <h4 class="blockTitle">Rule Builder</h4>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" id="objct">Show Objects</button>
                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $('#objct').click(function(){
                                $('#objList').show();
                            })                            
                        })
                    </script>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5" id="objList" style="display: none;height: auto; width: 200px;" >
                    <select class="SlectBox" size="8" multiple="multiple" title="Select objects">
                        <option value="Object_1">Object 1</option>
                        <option value="Object_2">Object 2</option>
                        <option value="Object_3">Object 3</option>
                        <option value="Object_4">Object 4</option>
                        <option value="Object_5">Object 5</option>
                        <option value="Object_6">Object 6</option>
                        <option value="Object_7">Object 7</option>
                        <option value="Object_8">Object 8</option>
                        <option value="Object_9">Object 9</option>
                        <option value="Object_10">Object 10</option>
                        <option value="Object_11">Object 11</option>
                    </select>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <button id="close" class="btn btn-default" style="float: right">OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br /><br />
            <p id="list"></p>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#SlectBox').multiselect({
                        includeSelectAllOption: true
                    });
                    $('#close').click(function(){
                        var objs = [];
                        $.each($(".SlectBox option:selected"), function(){            
                            objs.push($(this).val());
                        });
                        $( '#list' ).html(objs.join(", "));
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <br /><hr /><br />
            <select id="selctObjs" multiple="multiple" size="1">
                //Here I want to populate the list
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <br /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

What I select in the select box with the `class="SlectBox"` should be populate in the select box with `id="selctObjs"`.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another solution :

http://jsfiddle.net/wxfa98q1/

```
$('#close').click(function(){
    // Resize the select
    $('#selctObjs').attr('size',$(".SlectBox option:selected").length);
    // Empty children
    $('#selctObjs').empty();
    // For each selected options create one on the other select
    $.each($(".SlectBox option:selected"),function (i, item) {
            $('#selctObjs').append($('<option>', { 
                value: item.value,
                text : item.text 
            }));
     });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<body style="background-color: azure;" ng-app="app">
    <div id="container" style="padding: 50px 100px 50px 200px; width: 80%" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <div class="block" style="padding: 15px;">
            <h4 class="blockTitle">Rule Builder</h4>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" id="objct">Show Objects</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5" id="objList" style="height: auto; width: 200px;" >
                    <select class="SlectBox" size="8" multiple="multiple" title="Select objects">
                        <option value="Object_1">Object 1</option>
                        <option value="Object_2">Object 2</option>
                        <option value="Object_3">Object 3</option>
                        <option value="Object_4">Object 4</option>
                        <option value="Object_5">Object 5</option>
                        <option value="Object_6">Object 6</option>
                        <option value="Object_7">Object 7</option>
                        <option value="Object_8">Object 8</option>
                        <option value="Object_9">Object 9</option>
                        <option value="Object_10">Object 10</option>
                        <option value="Object_11">Object 11</option>
                    </select>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <button id="close" class="btn btn-default" style="float: right">OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br /><br />
            <p id="list"></p>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#objList').hide();
                    $('#objct').click(function(){

                        $('#objList').show();
                    }) 


                    $('#close').click(function(){
                        var objs = [];
                        var html = '';
                        $.each($(".SlectBox option:selected"), function(){            
                            objs.push($(this).val());
                            html += '<option value="'+$(this).val()+'">'+$(this).html()+'</option>';
                        });
                        $( '#list' ).html(objs.join(", "));
                        $('#selctObjs').html(html);
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <br /><hr /><br />
            <select id="selctObjs" multiple="multiple" size="1">

            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <br /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $('#close').click(function () {
     var objs = $(".SlectBox option:selected").map(function () {
         return this.value;
     }).get();
     $('#list').html(objs.join(", "));

     $("#selctObjs").html($(".SlectBox option:selected").clone());
 });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yegw1tqu/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you are getting the values from each selected option and putting them into an array. You could also add the html from those objects and put them in the array as well.

After that, I'd go through the entire array and do something like this:

```
var $selctObjs = $('#selctObjs');
objs.forEach(function(entry) {
    $selctObjs.append('<option value='+ entry.value +' >'+entry.html +'</option>');
});
```

Hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

You just replace the following tag:

```
 <select class="SlectBox" size="8" multiple="multiple" title="Select objects">
```

to

```
<select class="SlectBox" size="8" multiple="multiple" title="Select objects" onchange="qq(this)">
```

And then define a function named qq

```
function qq(v)
{
   alert(v.options[v.selectedIndex].value); //it prompt the select value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me your code is working fine only getting error for `$('#SlectBox').multiselect({
                        includeSelectAllOption: true
                    });`
this line of codes. Have you used any jquery plugin?

Please check my modified code

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/nsjquery/9vp4qfey/)

**html**

```
<body style="background-color: azure;" ng-app="app">
<div id="container" style="padding: 50px 100px 50px 200px; width: 80%" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="block" style="padding: 15px;">
        <h4 class="blockTitle">Rule Builder</h4>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-default" id="objct">Show Objects</button>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#objct').click(function(){
                            $('#objList').show();
                        })                            
                    })
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5" id="objList" style="display: none;height: auto; width: 200px;" >
                <select class="SlectBox" size="8" multiple="multiple" title="Select objects">
                    <option value="Object_1">Object 1</option>
                    <option value="Object_2">Object 2</option>
                    <option value="Object_3">Object 3</option>
                    <option value="Object_4">Object 4</option>
                    <option value="Object_5">Object 5</option>
                    <option value="Object_6">Object 6</option>
                    <option value="Object_7">Object 7</option>
                    <option value="Object_8">Object 8</option>
                    <option value="Object_9">Object 9</option>
                    <option value="Object_10">Object 10</option>
                    <option value="Object_11">Object 11</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <br />
                <button id="close" class="btn btn-default" style="float: right">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <p id="list"></p>
        <br /><hr /><br />
        <select id="selctObjs">
            //Here I want to populate the list
        </select>
        <br /><br />
        <br /><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

`$(function () {

```
                $('#close').click(function(){
                    var objs = [];
                    var optionList = "";
                    $.each($(".SlectBox option:selected"), function(){            
                        objs.push($(this).val());
                    });
                    $( '#list' ).html(objs.join(", "));
                    $("#selctObjs").html("");

                    $.each(objs,function(index){
                        optionList=optionList+"<option>"+objs[index]+"</option>"
                    })
                    $("#selctObjs").html(optionList);
                });
            });`
```